# YIN algorithm to find fundamental frequency

Tags: python, algorithm, signal-processing

I try to find fundamental frequency with several algorithms.

I found YIN algorithm(http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf)

I follow steps and write code.

the autocorrelation function from the document is:

[image]

and expected graph is :

[image]

so my sample code is:

```
def auto(lag, samples):
    window_size = 1100
    total_index = len(samples)
    zero_padded = np.append(samples, np.zeros(window_size))
    corr = []
    for t in range(total_index):
        r = 0
        for j in range(t+1, t+window_size):
            r += zero_padded[j] * zero_padded[j+lag]
        corr.append(r)

    plt.plot(corr)
    plt.show()
```

but got this graph:
    [image]
    [image: zoomed]

How should I edit my code?

Comment: Please tell us what the difference between these two graphs is. Is the "Expected" graph for an infinite signal? Is your signal actually infinite?

Comment: I don't see that you vary `lag`

Comment: @Eric  As the document shows, I expected autocorrelation graph to be parallel with x-axis. but my graph is going down.

Comment: @MBo should I vary lag?? I set the lag to 1

Comment: Your task is to build a graph - some magnitude (y-axis) versus lag (x-axis). Formula at the picture - r(tau), where tau is lag, I think.

Comment: @MBo so.. should I shift lag( 1, 2, 3 ...) instead of changing t?? I thought changing t is moving window.

Comment: Cited method is some kind of autocorrelation with window filters. If omit these windows, you have to: For tau in some range 0..max calculate the sum of F(j) * F(j + tau). But your code uses constant lag: `zero_padded[j] * zero_padded[j+lag]`. I would recommend to train skills with simple autocorrelations first.

Comment: Also, you're not going to get the expected output if you zero-pad

Comment: Regarding my first comment - you post contains two matplotlib graphs, What is the difference between them?

Comment: @Eric sorry for confusion. second graph is just zoomed of first one